# The center of a linear group with finite conjugacy classes has finite index

Tags: group-theory, linear-groups

Given a linear group $G\subset GL_n(k)$ with the property that every conjugacy class is finite (or equivalently, each centraliser has finite index), show that it follows that the center has finite index.

The converse is true for any group because the order of any conjugacy class is bounded by the index of the center by orbit-stabilisor.

So far I could only prove the result when $G$ is finitely generated, for then $Z(G)=\cap_{i=1}^nC_G{(g_i)}$ for some $g_i\in G$, and thus $|G:Z(G)|\le \prod_i|G:C_G{(g_i)}|<\infty$.

It was thinking maybe to somehow apply Schur's result on the Burnside problem (a periodic linear group is locally finite), but I am not sure this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of $G$ has a finite index centralizer, and hence every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ has finite index centralizer.

Let $F$ be a finite subset of $G$ whose centralizer $C$ in $M_n(k)$ has minimal dimension (observe that this centralizer is a subalgebra, hence a linear subspace). I claim that $C$ is the centralizer of $G$. Indeed, if $g\in G$, the centralizer of $F\cup\{g\}$ is contained in the centralizer $C$ of $F$, and hence equals $C$ by minimality of the dimension. Thus $C$ centralizes $g$. Since this holds for all $g$ we get the result.

Hence the center $C\cap G$ of $G$ coincides with the centralizer of $F$, and thus has finite index.

More generally, if $G$ is any FC-group (group all of whose conjugacy classes are finite) and satisfying the descending chain condition on centralizers (every descending chain of centralizers stabilizes), then $G$ has center of finite index. The descending chain condition on centralizers is satisfied by linear groups (in a strong sense, since there's a uniform bound on lengths of chains).

Comment: Nice to see it generalises to any subgroup of a finite dimensional $D$-algebra when $D$ is a division ring

Comment: How do you define a $D$-algebra with $D$ is not commutative? The usual definition of $D$-algebra for $D$ commutative assumes that $D$ is central. Your claim is even unclear for a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_1(D)$.

Comment: yeah you're right that was naive to say. thanks.

Comment: Do you know where the argument would fail? presupposedly because we cannot define dimension properly, but I'm not sure

Comment: Yes that's where it fails (centralizers are not left right $D$-linear subspace. Actually, there exists a skew field $D$ with a subgroup $G\subset D^*$ such that $G$ has an infinite decreasing chain of centralizers (but in the examples I know, $G$ is not an FC-group).